# Can't locate v-btn while shallow mounting a component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3, vue-test-utils

I have created a project in vuetify and now trying to unit test it using jest.
I have button that I have created using v-btn, which toggles the value of a boolean variable.

To check whether the button has been clicked, I tried to get hold of the button using the class name I gave to v-btn, but its not working

I have tried using shallow mounting and plain mounting. I tried to capture the tag (v-btn) itself, but it didn't work

some.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
  <v-btn class="profile-button" @click="isProfile = !isProfile">Profile</v-btn>
  <v-btn icon color="#fff" class="expand" small fab absolute right @click="mini = !mini">
     <v-icon color="#fcbc00">chevron_right</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   data() {
    return {
     isProfile: true,
     mini: true
    }
   }
  }
</script>
```

some.spec.js

```
 import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
 import Profile from '@/components/Profile.vue';
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

 describe('Profile.vue', () => {

  Vue.use(Vuetify)

  it('Profile is a vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Profile);
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  });

  it('Profile Button exists', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Profile);
    expect(wrapper.contains('.profile-button')).toBe(true)
  });

  it('Profile Button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Profile);
    expect(wrapper.contains('.profile-button')).trigger('click')
  });

  it('Has an expand button', () => {
   const wrapper = shallowMount(Profile)
   wrapper.find('expand').trigger('click')
})
```

});

All the tests should be passed. But I receive the following error:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: false

  19 |     
  20 |     it('Profile Button exists', () => {
> 21 |       expect(wrapper.contains('.profile-button')).toBe(true)
     |                                                   ^
  22 |     })


[vue-test-utils]: find did not return expand, cannot call trigger() 
 on empty Wrapper

  16 |     it('Has an expand button', () => {
  17 |       const wrapper = shallowMount(SideDrawer)
> 18 |       wrapper.find('expand').trigger('click')
     |                              ^
  19 |     })
  20 |   });
```

What should I do? I have many such buttons that I need to test and I am stuck, as I tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution!

I was asserting the value of **wrapper.find('.profile-button')** with true.

It should be changed to:

```
(wrapper.find('.profile-button').exists()).toBe(true)
```

**(wrapper.find('.profile-button').exists())** returns a boolean value, which is what we want to assert.